# Symfony3 Tow differents authentications (cas+form) with only one provider

Tags: authentication, symfony

For my project I have

- A User class with all my users
- A login_form authentication (works fine)
- A CAS authentification with PhpCAS + Guard (works fine)

But when I want to enable both authentications in the same time I have a problem. As soon that I'm login with the login form I'm redirected to the CAS login page :-/

Security.yml

```
    ...
    pattern:    ^/
    anonymous: false
    form_login:
            provider: user_provider
            login_path: login_route
            check_path: login_check
            default_target_path: homepage
        logout:
             path:   /logout
        switch_user: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
              - xxxx.cas_authenticator
    ...
```

CasAuthenticator.php

```
...
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
  \phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, $url, $port, "/cas");
  \phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
  \phpCAS::handleLogoutRequests();
  \phpCAS::forceAuthentication();
  if (\phpCAS::getUser()) {
    return \phpCAS::getUser();
  }
return null;
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
  return $this->em->getRepository('LfayBundle:User\User')
                ->findOneBy(array('username' => $credentials ));
}
...
```

Where am I wrong ?
If someone have an idea ...